# Image filtering

Tags: matlab, filter

I have a problem with removing the line artifact from the OCT image. I trying wiener and median filtering but nothing works well.

[image]

In this picture is clearly visible line artifact in both directions.

I have I more picture with I take by averaging 450 images in Z axe.

[image]

Can you help me? please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try a Gaussian blur by a few pixels.  Then, for each column subtract the median pixel.  Repeat for the rows.

Answer (score 1):

Another option might be to Fourier filter your image with two masks of sincs (sinc(x)=sin(x)/x) functions for vertical and horizontal lines. On a different note, from what I see you may want to improve data acquisition by understanding where these lines come from (i.e. take a background image, where you "scan" nothing and compensate for shot noise of the detector etc)

Comment: I'm really sorry but i can't implement it to MATLAB could you please write it in matlab source code ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about the vertical lines then since the lines are quite narrow you could use morphological operators, e.g. 1x7 horizontal erode (min) followed by 1x7 horizontal dilate (max).